# Java Urlclass loader cast exception

Tags: java, java-10

Here I am try to get the file urls dynamically to set to compiler in code.
I'm using code to get those by casting the class loader got from thread context and then cast it to UrlclassLoader and then call getUrls method.
But in Java 10 it is not supported as per documentation.
Is there any alternative for this?

Comment: May be some other approach to get urlclasspath for classpath jars.

Comment: Could you share some code to show what exactly are you trying to achieve? I am pretty sure there are similar question with java-9 tags you can lookup for. If they still do not cover your use case, please elaborate.

Comment: Here is the same code : <code> UrlclassLoader ul = (UrlclassLoader) Thread.currentthread().getcontext.getclassLoader();  URL urls[] = UL.geturls(); </code> urls[] needed for further processing

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49557431/how-to-safely-access-the-urls-of-all-resource-files-in-the-classpath-in-java-9-1

Comment: @KartikParihar You will find the answers to [How to safely access the URLs of all resource files in the classpath in Java 9/10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49557431/how-to-safely-access-the-urls-of-all-resource-files-in-the-classpath-in-java-9-1) solve your problem, particularly [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49557901/2525313).

Comment: You still didn’t say what you want to do with this URLs. Until you describe your “further processing”, I consider your question a typical xy-problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I consider the approaches provided and it worked for me.

Comment: I have written a maven mojo to compile JSP file, this need to update the classpath at runtime with file urls. And set it to mojo compiler.

Comment: As of now there's no dynamic values updated in class path. So, I have used the similar response as mentioned by @Nicolai.